# Drop down value should change according Radio Button

Tags: javascript, php

I need drop down select value will change dynamically according to two radio button. For example here in my html code , if select country 1 from country and select city1 from city then drop down value will be set 1
and if select country 1 from country and select city2  from city then drop down value will be set 2.
I need JavaScript or php code.

Thanks for any help.

```
<div class='aQuestion' id='div1'>
    <STRONG>1. </STRONG>
    <STRONG>Country</STRONG></br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp1' VALUE='Country 0'>Country1</br>



</div>

<div class='aQuestion' id='div2'>
    <STRONG>2. </STRONG>
    <STRONG>City</STRONG></br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='City 0'>City 1</br>
    <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='City1'>City 2</br>


</div><br/>

<div> set 1 
<select name="school">

<option value="school1">school 1</option>;
<option value="school2">school 2</option>;
<option value="school3">school 3</option>;


</select><br/>
</div><br/>


<div>
 set 2
<select name="school">

<option value="school4">school 4</option>;
<option value="school5">school 5</option>;
<option value="school6">school 6</option>;

</select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you select country2 and city1, then?

Comment: Some JS code ? Did you try something ?

Comment: If select country2 and city1, then set 2 drop down will display, set 1 will not display.  @I Can Has Cheezburger

Comment: For what all scenarios SET 1 should be displayed and for what all SET 2 should be displayed ?

Comment: if  check radio button Country1 and radio button City 1 then SET 1 should be display,  if  check radio button Country1 and radio button City 2 then SET 2 should be display

Comment: @user3176335 ok, then what abt country3,4 and city3,4.

Comment: this process will continue ,then  set 3 and set 4, set 5 ... will display  @ Navin

Comment: @user3176335 How many sets do you have there? And why do I feel like your logic is terribly collapsing?

Comment: Created the Plnker for your reference, check [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KsVXJcrwUuv2kpyMRLgW?p=preview), if this is what you want..

Comment: I have edited my code, now only two set for two type radio button    @user3176335

Comment: @user3176335: Check out my Plnker.
Actually this is not the correct way to do this, I think what you want is when user selectes Any country and city, so you want the list of all schools for the selected items. So, best thing why not make a ajax request to fetch all the lists and create the dynamic list of schools, based on user selected values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='City 0'>City 1</br>
<INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='City1'>City 2</br>
```

with

```
 <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='City 0' onClick="javascript:return yourfunction(1)">City 1</br>
 <INPUT TYPE='radio' NAME='grp2' VALUE='City1' onClick="javascript:return yourfunction(2)">City 2</br>
```

JavaScript code

```
function yourfunction(radioid)
{
  if(radioid == 1)
  {    
document.getElementById('one').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else if(radioid == 2)
  {  
   document.getElementById('two').style.display = '';
   document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Working Model, Refer this

http://jsfiddle.net/NWWL4/23/

hope this helps